# Jenkins running Linux shell program does not reccogize commands

Tags: linux, perl, shell, curl, jenkins

I have the following code running on my jenkins build step: "execute shell"

```
#!/bin/sh
workspaceDirectory=WORKSPACE
appName=ClaimCenter

perl WORKSPACE/directory/scripts/FileLoaderDoItTwiceFinal.pl  $workspaceDirectory $appName
curl --ntlm --user myUserName:myPassword --upload-file WORKSPACE/directory/test/ClaimCenterUnmatchedProperties.csv     https://sharpoint/share/sharesight/TrainingManuals/RTC/PropertyFileAnalyzer/filename.csv`

appName=ContactManager

perl WORKSPACE/dircectory/scripts/FileLoaderDoItTwiceFinal.pl $workspaceDirectory $appName
curl --ntlm --user myUserName:MyPassWord --upload-file WORKSPACE/CliamCenterBatch/test/ContactManagerUnmatchedProperties.csv
https://sharpoint/share/sharesight/TrainingManuals/RTC/PropertyFileAnalyzer/filename.csv`
```

Jenkins builds for a long time so it is very difficult to test repeatedly but after the build opperations happen, the following is output to the jenkins console:

```
 [TEST-SAMPLE-BUILD-CLAIMS_Dev_Tools_blucas-DEF] $ /bin/sh/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh
/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh: line 5: perl: command not found
/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh: line 6: curl: command not found
/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh: line 10: perl: command not found
/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh: line 11: curl: command not found
/tmp/hudson4025671051509183982.sh: line 12: https://sharpoint/share/sharesight/TrainingManuals/RTC/PropertyFileAnalyzer/filename.csv` : No such file or directory
```

please help me understand why this build is not understanding these commands

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that `perl` and `curl` binaries couldn't be found, which means that the environment for your script does not have `PATH` environment variable set.

To fix this, use the full paths to the binaries, instead of just their names. eg:

```
/usr/bin/perl WORKSPACE/directory/scripts/FileLoaderDoItTwiceFinal.pl $workspaceDirectory $appName

/usr/bin/curl --ntlm --user myUserName:myPassword --upload-file WORKSPACE/directory/test/ClaimCenterUnmatchedProperties.csv     https://sharpoint/share/sharesight/TrainingManuals/RTC/PropertyFileAnalyzer/filename.csv`
```

Comment: now it just says no such file or directory instead of no command